# How to wait for UITextField becomeFirstResponder before insertText?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How to wait for `UITextField` `becomeFirstResponder` before `insertText`?

- A `UITextField` is the first responder.
- Then a modal view pops up and kills the `UITextField` focus (keyboard is gone)
- The modal view finishes and notifies via `delegate.thingsDone`
- `delegate.thingsDone` tries to `insertText` into the `UITextField` ...
- (Oops, the `UITextField` is not the first responder yet)

The situation is, I have a `NSString *` in hand and wants to `insertText` into the `UITextField` ***as soon as*** it `becomeFirstResponder`.

What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Why do you need the text field to be the first responder before you can add text to it?

Comment: I want to leave the OS to handle cursor position, selected text, etc.

Comment: stumped.  i'm going to remove my answer that misunderstands the question.  i think the problem is you want to preserve selection state in a way that's durable over changes in firstResponder.  that would be easy if UITextField gave any get or set access to selection range, but i don't see that it does.